# How do I send etheream to a contract?

Tags: contract-development, transactions

I'm trying to send ethereal from a wallet address to a smart contract address and... well, it doesn't seem to work. Perhaps someone can help me find out what I'm doing wrong? Here is my code.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    EtherInterface ei = new EtherInterface();
    ei.Start("http://127.0.0.1:8080", "", "1qaswedc2");
    System.out.println(ei.credentials.getEcKeyPair().getPrivateKey());

    System.out.println("---");

    EthGetTransactionCount ethGetTransactionCount = ei.web3j.ethGetTransactionCount("0x53529C6aB84011ea0e5A8354b053Cf69d30c6b4B", DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST).sendAsync().get();
    BigInteger nonce = ethGetTransactionCount.getTransactionCount();
    RawTransaction rtrans = RawTransaction.createEtherTransaction(nonce, BigInteger.valueOf(92000000000L), BigInteger.valueOf(92000000000L), "0x0eed97FbEa07Fe88CB6348A77FD8516bB7E42FE9", BigInteger.valueOf(10000000000000l));
    byte[] signedMessage = TransactionEncoder.signMessage(rtrans, ei.credentials);
    String hexVal = Numeric.toHexString(signedMessage);
    EthSendTransaction ethSendTransaction = ei.web3j.ethSendRawTransaction(hexVal).send();
    String transactionHash = ethSendTransaction.getTransactionHash();

    System.out.println(transactionHash);

  }
```

EtherInterface is something I made to make connecting to my local ether node easier. It looks like this:

```
public class EtherInterface {

  public Web3j web3j = null;
  public Credentials credentials = null;
  public Admin admin = null;
  //private static BigInteger gasLimit = null;

  public void Start(String host, String address, String password) throws Exception {

    web3j = Web3j.build(new HttpService(host));

    Admin web3j = Admin.build(new HttpService(host));

    Web3ClientVersion web3ClientVersion = web3j.web3ClientVersion().send();
    String clientVersion = web3ClientVersion.getWeb3ClientVersion();
    System.out.println(clientVersion);

    loginCredentials(address, password);
  }

  private void loginCredentials(String address, String password) throws IOException, CipherException {

    String walletFilePath = "REDACTED";
    credentials = WalletUtils.loadCredentials(password, walletFilePath);

  }
}
```

My smart contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;
contract Tenno2 {

/*
struct Weapon {
    string name;
    uint rank;
    bool potato;
}
*/
address Player;

string Warframe = "Ember Prime";
uint Rank = 1;
bool Potato = false;
uint HP = 150;
uint MP = 200;

//Weapon Primary;
//Weapon Secondary;
//Weapon Melee;

constructor() public payable {
    Player = msg.sender;

}

event AbilityUsed(string ability);
event Restored(uint health, uint energy);
event RankChange(uint rank);



function getWarframe() public constant returns (string) { return Warframe; }

function getPotato() public constant returns (bool) { return Potato; }
function PotatoFrame() public { Potato = true; }

function getHP() public constant returns (uint) { return HP; }
function getMP() public constant returns (uint) { return MP; }

function getRank() public constant returns (uint) { return Rank; }
function getCapacity() public constant returns(uint) {
    if (Potato == true) {
        return Rank * 2;
    }
    else {
        return Rank;
    }
}

function First() public{
    if (MP >= 25) {
        MP -= 25;
    }
    emit AbilityUsed("Fireball");
}

function Second() public {
    if (MP >= 50) {
        MP -= 50;
    }
    emit AbilityUsed("Accelerant");
}

function Thirth() public {
    if (MP >= 75) {
        MP -= 75;
    }
    emit AbilityUsed("Fireblast");
}

function Fourth() public {
    if (MP >= 100) {
        MP -= 100;
    }
    emit AbilityUsed("World on Fire");
}

function Heal(uint amount) public returns (uint) {
    HP += amount;
    emit Restored(amount, 0);
    return HP;
}

function TakeDamage(uint amount) public returns (uint) {
    HP -= amount;
    return HP;
}

function Recharge(uint amount) public returns (uint) {
    MP += amount;
    emit Restored(0, amount);
    return MP;
}

function RankUp() public returns (uint) {
    if (Rank < 30) {
        Rank += 1;
    }
    emit RankChange(Rank);
    return Rank;
}

function ResetRank() public returns (uint) {
    if (Rank == 30) {
        Rank = 1;
    }
    emit RankChange(Rank);
    return Rank;
}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Doesn't work"? Are you unable to sign a transaction? Broadcast it? Does the transaction get mined and fail?

Comment: So I see the transaction in the geth output, but when I check the balance of the smart contract, it stays at zero. I can even look at the transaction in the console.

Comment: Are you invoking a payable function in the smart contract?

Comment: I am not. Do I make the transaction and then invoke a payable function?

Comment: Your contract must have at least one payable function (usually the fallback function) before it can receive ether. What is your contract's code?

Comment: Just added my smart contract to the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have a payable function in your contract (besides the constructor, but that cannot be invoked after deployment).

Try adding a payable fallback:

```
function() public payable {

}
```

Then, send ether again with a regular transaction (no msg.data).

If you need any specific function to receive ether, you will need to mark that as payable too.

Comment: Thank you. I feel dumb, but I love you. Again, thanks.